# PCB Protection Circuit for LiPo batteries doesn't output a voltage

Tags: voltage, lipo

I have two LiPo batteries (18650) connected to a 2s PCB protection circuit. I can read a voltage at the b+ and b-, which is about 7.03 V but there's no voltage at p+ and p-. Is there something wrong with my circuit or is my board damaged? 
Here some Images of my build. Sorry for the Google photos link, I get an error if I try to attach my photos to this post.

[image]
https://photos.app.goo.gl/oVLaHCQpMJgqAEr68

Comment: please disconnect the red wires and measure again. No idea what the blue PCB is doing. Mostly, yes something is wrong with the blue PCB.. are the batteries hot?

Comment: No the batteries are cold, but I got a short circuit when I attached the cables, could that have damaged the PCB?

Comment: Yes. If there was a short circuit you proobibly killed it.

Comment: the PCB gave away it's life for no reason. Why don't you remove the blue PCB and see. before that, again i ask to measure the voltage after removing the red cables.

Comment: Ok I detached the cables and I still measure no voltage at p+ and p-, than I have probably killed the board,

Comment: can you flip the blue PCB without desoldering to see what is wrong?

Comment: I have now desoldered everything, the backplate looks normal to me

Comment: Can you put a pic.. Can you measure the resistance between P+ and P-

Comment: The resistance is 11.5 with multimeter adjusted to 20k,